How to set the default value of a signal as the default value of an option element in an HTML select element?
I'm using Fresh/Preact. In an HTML select element, I want 2 things:

The value of the selected option is displayed next by
The default value of a signal is the default value of an option element

Attempt 1: simple setup
import { signal } from "@preact/signals";

const pet = signal(undefined)
function Pets() {
  return (
    <>
      <select value={pet.value} onChange={e => pet.value = e.target.value} >
        <option selected value="dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      </select>
      {pet.value} 
    </>
  );
}

render(<Pets />, document.getElementById("app"));

The default selected option isn't got initially. As the options are generated, I cannot specify the default value of the signal.
Playground
Attempt 2: generating the options and select default value via a loop
import { signal } from "@preact/signals";

const pet = signal(undefined)
const arr = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Hamster'] 

function Pets() {
    const options = [] 
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (arr.indexOf(item) === 0){
            options.push(<option selected value={item}>{item}</option>)
            pet.value = item
        }  else {
            options.push(<option value={item}>{item}</option>)
        } 
    } 
    return (
    <>
      <select value={pet.value} onChange={e => pet.value = e.target.value} >
        {options}
      </select>
      {pet.value} 
    </>
  );
}

render(<Pets />, document.getElementById("app"));

The select element freezes, I can't select other options. Playground
I think it's because the code is inside the component, so every time it renders the default value is reset.
Attempt 3: Moving the loop outside of the component
import { signal } from "@preact/signals";

const pet = signal(undefined)
const arr = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Hamster'] 
const options = [] 
for (const item of arr) {
    if (arr.indexOf(item) === 0){
        options.push(<option selected value={item}>{item}</option>)
        pet.value = item
    }  else {
        options.push(<option value={item}>{item}</option>)
    } 
} 
function Pets() {

    return (
    <>
      <select value={pet.value} onChange={e => pet.value = e.target.value} >
                {options}
      </select>
      {pet.value} 
    </>
  );
}

render(<Pets />, document.getElementById("app"));

This fixes the problem. Nevertheless it still leaves me two unsolved questions:

Why doesn't attempt 2 work? In my understanding the signal won't re-render the whole component but just the text.
Inspecting the result I see that there is no selected option


Are the options passed into the component as props, a list you fetch, etc? You could generally iterate over the list to get the default value, something like if (typeof pet.value == 'undefined') options.forEach(option => { if (option.selected) pet.value = option.value } );. Would need to know a bit more about your set up to give a better answer, though this is the sort of approach you'll need to use to pull a default value out of your options and assign it to the signal to initialize it.

I update the question to reflect the problem of this. Can you take a look?


I think it's because the code is inside the component, so every time it renders the default value is reset.

No, the issue is that you skipped a rather key part of my comment (and therefore have a fundamental rendering flaw): you set pet.value to the first item upon every rerender. Once you rerender the component, you're setting it again. That's why we need the if (typeof pet.value == 'undefined'), we only set the value if this is the first run and the value is undefined still. On subsequent runs, we skip this.
Here's how you could make that work:
import { signal } from "@preact/signals";

const pet = signal(undefined)
const arr = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Hamster'] 

function Pets() {
  const options = arr.map((item, idx) => {
    if (typeof pet.value == 'undefined' && idx == 0) pet.value = item;
    return <option selected={pet.value == item} value={item}>{item}</option>;
  });

  return (
    <>
      <select value={pet.value} onChange={e => pet.value = e.target.value} >
        {options}
      </select>
      {pet.value} 
    </>
  );
}

render(<Pets />, document.getElementById("app"));



In my understanding the signal won't re-render the whole component but just the text.

Signals can skip rerendering, but not in your case. You're accessing the signal within the loop (and the component), so upon signal change, your component must rerender. Additionally, with your API (generating a list of options, one with selected), that has to run every time the signal value changes. There's simply no way around that.

Inspecting the result I see that there is no selected option

Preact sets the property, not the attribute. In Firefox, you can right click on a DOM element and select "Show DOM properties" to get the full read out, and in this, you'll see selected: true. I'm sure Chrome has some sort of equivilant.
DOM properties and HTML attributes are related, but ultimately, two different things.

You didn't ask, but I'd try instead use a computed in your third example, like this:
import { signal, computed } from "@preact/signals";

const pet = signal(undefined)
const arr = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Hamster']

const options = computed(() =>
  arr.map((item, idx) => {
    if (typeof pet.value == 'undefined' && idx == 0) pet.value = item;
    return <option selected={pet.value == item} value={item}>{item}</option>;
  })
);

function Pets() {
  return (
    <>
      <select value={pet.value} onChange={e => pet.value = e.target.value} >
        {options}
      </select>
      {pet.value} 
    </>
  );
}

render(<Pets />, document.getElementById("app"));


TIL that DOM property and HTML attribute are different things. Thanks. Re: "you set pet.value to the first item upon every rerender. Once you rerender the component, you're setting it again", how is that different to what I said? It seems like you agree with me. Do you mean that in your version you don't use the for statement but the map method, so you can avoid having the component re-render when the value changes?

I forgot to check whether pet.value is undefined or not before assigning the value. I wonder why you check typeof instead of just directly the value? With the latter you can golf it to if (!pet.value) pet.value = item (if you use the for statement instead of the map method). Also, what's the benefit of computed? Reading the Signals docs I'm still unclear on what it does.

It's not quite the same, it basically comes down to the "owner" (wrapper) of a signal access. In your JSX ({pet.value}), the owner is the DOM node; in a computed(), it's the computed; in your example, it's the component. You could wrap that in useComputed() in the component and it'd skip rerendering the whole thing. In this example, however, that wouldn't make much sense to do as the component is rather empty, so I didn't show it, but would be a viable approach.

!pet.value would be truthy if the value was null, false, an empty string (''), etc. That check can therefore work with more data types without issue; !pet.value absolutely could be valid, just depends on what kind of data you're working with is all. computed is to create a signal from another signal, a sort of derived (or computed) value. It lets us avoid rerunning the whole module on change, just updating the computed and passing on its results to all who subscribe to it.
